# Calling method in Bean property attribute

Tags: java

I have a simple bean tag in the bean xml file as shown below. This is just a dummy values

```
<bean id="myBeanId" class="myBeanClass">
    <property name="myProperty" value=${myPassword} />
</bean>

<bean id ="myOtherBeanId" class="myOtherBeanClass">
    <property name="myOtherProperty" ref="myBeanId">
</bean>
```

myPassword is a variable names stored in a separate properties file. Now, I instead of storing the direct value of myPassword from the properties file, I will have encrypted string in the property file and I want to call my custom written Decrypt method on myPassword property instead. something like this.

```
<bean id="myBeanId" class="myBeanClass">
    <property name="myProperty" value=com.xxx.Security.Decrypt(${myPassword}) />
</bean>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Thanks Prasad for editing this question for formatting.

Comment: Please add more context to your question. What kind of "bean xml file" do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the MethodInvokingFactoryBean if you want to invoke another bean's method and use the returned object as a bean.

```
<bean id="securityBean" class="com.xxx.Security">
</bean>

<bean id="myBeanId" class="myBeanClass">
    <property name="myProperty">
        <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
           <property name="targetObject"><ref local="securityBean"/></property>
           <property name="targetMethod"><value>Decrypt</value></property>
           <property name="arguments">
               <list>
               <value>${myPassword}</value>
              </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Tried this. It does not work. Why have you use the constructor-arg tag. Decrypt is not the name of my class. It is just a non-static method.

Comment: I dont want to make that method static. Is there any other approach to call non-static method in bean xml?

Comment: Ok, I thought the method is a static method. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about Using with `jaspyt`,

Properties file entry
    password=ENC(G6N718UuyPE5bHyWKyuLQSm02auQPUtm)

Bean Entry

```
<bean id="myBeanId" class="myBeanClass">
    <property name="myProperty" value=${password} />
</bean>
```

Source : http://www.jasypt.org/spring31.html